# How to load library/ maven dependency in AWS EMR notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, spark-notebook

I am using AWS notebook. I can run normal scala based spark jobs without third-party library dependency fine. But I want to load some common libraries like typesafe-config, mysql-connector etc.

How can I add these library dependency in scala spark notebook on AWS?

I tried adding these snippets in first cell of notebook, but neither worked

```
 %%configure -f
    {
        "conf": {
            "spark.jars": "s3://bucket-xxx/jars/lib/config-1.3.1.jar"
        }
    }
```

as well as

```
%%configure -f
{
"conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "com.typesafe:config:1.3.1,mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17"},

"jars": ["s3://bucket-xxx/jars/lib/"]

}
```

both threw the error

> console>:29: error: object ConfigFactor is not a member of package
>   com.typesafe.config
>          import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactor

when I tried to import the typesafe config

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactor
```

I also tried adding maven coordinates in notebook metadata as

```
"customDeps": [
        "com.typesafe:config:1.3.1"
    ]
```

and got

> error: object typesafe is not a member of package com
>          import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in import line, it should be

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
```

In addition this cell is required in Jupyter notebook

```
%%configure -f 
{
  "jars": ["s3://test/libs/config-1.3.1.jar"],
  "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "com.typesafe:config:1.3.1"}
}
```

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: side question, why do you have to provide jar and also maven repo? Isn't only one of them enough?